# AS3 How to make Fog Of War

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have complete a maze game that a character walks arounds, collects things and shoots enemies. The game is produced entirely dynamically. I now want to add a fog of war where the character can only see whats around him on a certain circle radius. I have created the images and background images using sprites/movie clips.

My original idea was to create 5*5 black squares over the entire map and have them all running an eventlistener to see if they are hit or not and change the alpha to 0 if they are hit. But I think that it might bog down the game with too many EVENTs active. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to ask here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you need to create a fog of war on a minimap, so that hero only sees enemies, etc. around a predefined radius and can also see terrain if he has visited that part of the map. Something like this:

[image]

Where yellow paw is hero and red dots are enemies. Darker parts of the map have not been visited yet.

You can achieve this effect by using 2 masks, 1 for masking revealed part of the terrain and another one for masking the highlighted part of the terrain and enemies or other objects. So your layer structure should be something like this:

[image]

After setting up your layers, you can simply call the

```
beginFill(0xFF0000); // any color will do
drawCircle(mHero.x, mHero.y, radius);
endFill();
```

methods on the `graphics` object of darkened terrain mask (lower one). mHero is the instance name for the hero symbol on the minimap.

That's for the revealing part, for the highlight of the hero's position on the minimap you'll need to do the same for the highlighted terrain mask, but with the addition of `clear()` method at each draw call, so that old circles don't get saved. You'll have something like this for the highlighted terrain map graphics object:

```
clear();
beginFill(0xFF0000); // any color will do
drawCircle(mHero.x, mHero.y, radius);
endFill();
```